# knockout.js taking forever to render html with large array in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, knockout.js

I have an array of 1406 with three string properties for each object in it. But it never renders in Chrome, just freezes the page.  It works in IE just fine.  The problem happens from the push.apply.  I am using knockout.js 2.20.  Why would this take forever?  I send one item into the array and it works just fine.  Shouldnt knockout be able to handle 1406 items in an array?

```
 <div data-bind="foreach: powerSchoolCourses">
                            <div data-bind="html: courseName"></div>
                        </div>

    var convertedPowerSchoolCourses = ko.utils.arrayMap(powerSchoolCourses, function (jsonArrayFromService) {
                        return new PowerSchool(item);
                    });
    self.powerSchoolCourses.push.apply(self.powerSchoolCourses, convertedPowerSchoolCourses );


        function PowerSchool(data) {
            var self = this;
            self.courseName = ko.observable(data.courseName);
            self.courseNumber = ko.observable(data.courseNumber);
            self.id = ko.observable(data.id);
        }
```

Comment: Not to be douchey, but you said it never renders in Chrome and then asks why it takes so long... does it infact render in chrome but just take a long time or never render in chrome with a possibly slightly misleading question?

Comment: It wasnt rendering, until I switched to containerless control flow syntax, but now it renders super slow, but at least renders after 20 seconds or so, before it froze the browser.

Comment: Do those properties on the model actually need to be observables? In other words, are you really wanting to do complete dependency tracking on all 1406 items or are you just wanting to display them?

Comment: Still takes forever when I make them static properties.

Comment: And its only taking forever in chrome? IE renders close to immediately?

Comment: If I remove the whole foreach div, it loads fast!

Comment: any chance of a jsfiddle showing issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should of done this in the first place.  Restarting my computer did something with Chrome.  Working just fine now, sorry for the confusion.  Rule #1 always restart your computer if something doesn't work right.

Comment: Please delete your question, because it will probably not be useful to any of the future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

In regards to this code:

```
var convertedPowerSchoolCourses = 
  ko.utils.arrayMap(powerSchoolCourses, function (jsonArrayFromService) {
      return new PowerSchool(item);
});
```

I think you might be giving the wrong parameters to the [arrayMap](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/utility-functions-in-knockoutjs.html) function.  The first parameter should be the raw data that comes from your service, and the function in the second parameter has a parameter that should be used inside the function.  So I think what you really need to do is this:

```
var convertedPowerSchoolCourses = 
  ko.utils.arrayMap(jsonArrayFromService, function (item) {
      return new PowerSchool(item);
});
```